# C++ encrypt and decrypt secret messages using files

Tags: c++, encryption

I have my prototypes in a header file, but I need some help.  I am having some trouble getting the program to compile all the way through.  It appears to be getting caught in a loop with the input.  Possibly some issues with the functions.   Thanks in advance for any input.

```
 #include <iostream>
  #include <conio.h>
   #include "header.h" 
   #include <fstream>  
 class Caesar  
  {  
  public: void readText(char *input);  
      void encrypt(char *input,char *output,char *key);  
     void decrypt(char *input,char *output,char *key);  

    }; 

void main()  
 {  
Caesar a;  
 char key[1000];  
ifstream fin;
 int choice;
char input[100],output[100];  

 cout<<"\n Enter input file: ";  
 cin>>input;  
 cout << input;
 cout<<"\n Enter output file: ";  
 cin>>output; 
 cout <<output;
 cout<<"\n Enter key: ";  
 cin>>key; 
 cout <<key;
 cout<<"\n\n 1. Encrypt\n 2. Decrypt\n\n Select choice(1 or 2): "<< endl;  
 cin >> choice;
 cout << choice;
 a.readText(input); 
 if(choice==1)  
 {
   a.encrypt(input,output,key);  
 }
 if(choice==2)  
 {
     a.decrypt(input,output,key);  
 }
  else  
 {
    cout<<"\n\n Unknown choice";  
 }

 }    

void Caesar::readText(char *input)  
{  
 ifstream reader;  
 char buf;  
 reader.open(input);  
 cout<<"\n\n <--- "<<input<<" --->\n";  
 buf=reader.get();  
 while(!reader.eof())  
 {  
  cout<<buf;  
  buf=reader.get();  
 }  
 reader.close();  
 }  

  void Caesar::encrypt(char *input,char *output,char *key)  
  {  
  ifstream reader;  
  ofstream writer;  
  char buf;  
  reader.open(input);  
  writer.open(output);  
  buf=reader.get();  
  while(!reader.eof())  
  {  
    if(buf>='a'&&buf<='z')  
   {  
     buf-='a';  
     buf+=key[buf];  
     buf%=26;  
     buf+='A';  
    }  
    writer.put(buf);  
    buf=reader.get();  
    }  
   reader.close();  
   writer.close();  
   readText(input);  
   readText(output);  
   }  

  void Caesar::decrypt(char *input,char *output,char *key)  
  {  
   ifstream reader;  
   ofstream writer;  
   char buf;  
   reader.open(input);  
   writer.open(output);  
   buf=reader.get();  
   while(!reader.eof())  
  {  
  if(buf>='A'&&buf<='Z')  
  {  
     buf-='A';  
     buf+=26-key[buf];  
     buf%=26;  
     buf+='a';  
   }  
   writer.put(buf);  
   buf=reader.get();  
   }  
  reader.close();  
  writer.close();  
  readText(input);  
  readText(output);  
 }
```

Comment: What Environment are you coding in please name your IDE and compiler.
Have you written a simple `cin >>` and `cout <<` code in this environment before?

Comment: I am using C++ and compiling in Microsoft Visual Studios 2012.  I've been using it all semester but I don't know why I'm struggling with the cin.

Comment: Just clean and rebuild your project after restarting the visual studio and see the result.What do you mean exactly by saying freeze.Does any input from your keyboard display? How much time it freezes and goes to the next line of code? And what is your input if it is displayed on screen?

Comment: It won't let me type anything into the value for "Select choice(1 or 2)".  It exits out of the program.

Comment: Just clean out every thing in your code except a `cin >>` and `cout <<` and tell me the result.I just want to make sure that every thing with compiler and IDE is ok.

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 void main()  
 {  
  
     char input[1000];

         cout<<"\n Enter input file: ";  
         cin>>input;  
         cout << input;
 }
It works when I just use the cin/cout

Comment: Almost forgot the using namespace std; it works fine but not with the program I wrote.

Comment: After cleaning every thing except a `cout <<` and `cin>>` add the simple parts of your code and try executing it.just try to complete the main part.

Comment: I started to cout all the variables that I was inputting and it looks like the key1.txt is where the odd numbers are coming from.  Is there something wrong with the file or do I have key declared wrong?

Comment: Please make your edit your question and make it clear Because I have already showed you that there is no problem with `cin` Your Caesar  encryption function has some problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(choice=1)
```

should be

```
if(choice==1)
```

and also in the other `if`

In your case, you are assigning the value `1` to `choice`, then test if `choice` is `true`, and it is, since any non-zero numeral type is implicitly casted to `bool` `true`.

Comment: I changed it to (choice == 1) but it won't let me enter a value when I run the program.  I put cout<<choice; after the cin>>choice to see if it's even going through.  The cout value is -858993460 but it won't let me enter a value.  I tried initializing choice but then it only spits out what I initialize it to.  Any ideas?

Comment: @goldylocks, are you sure? Try running the program from the terminal, it should read the choice correctly.

Comment: Cannot find or open the PDB file. This is the error it gives me.

Answer (score 0):

I have just executed your code and tried debugging it and took a screen shot

you program gets into a loop after entering the choice.there is no problem with `cin>>`.

[image]

Comment: I changed them to
if(choice ==1)
and
if(choice==2)
It still won't let me enter a value when I run the program.

Comment: It gets stuck when I try using a file.  How do I avoid the loop?

Comment: Please first edit the Question as I commented on your Question to make it clear for others.

Comment: I edited the question and changed my code so that key is a char so I can hold the data in the file.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems like you're just trying to debug main.  Everything seems to work fine.  What are you inputting for key?  If it's a very large integer, that may be your problem as it might exceed the maximum integer range and cause overflow.

Your key is an integer variable.  You are inputting a string for the file name that holds your key, so that should be changed to a C string array.  Change all of the passed key parameters to char* instead of int.

You have an infinite loop when the readText() function is called.

Maybe try this:

```
void Caesar::readText(char *input)  
{  
    ifstream reader(input);
    if(reader.is_open())
    {
        char buf;
        cout<<"\n\n <--- "<<input<<" --->\n"; 
        while(reader.get(buf))
        {
            cout << buf;
        }
    }    
    reader.close();  
}
```

Make sure that your text file is in the same folder as your code.  See this for more details:  [ifstream not opening file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961630/ifstream-not-opening-file)

Comment: I have .txt for each input.  I have key1.txt which says "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
crazy fredericka bought many very equisite opal jewels
amazingly few discotheques provide jukeboxes
sphinx of black quartz judge my vow" I tried changing the arrays to 1000 but it didn't change the output.  Is there something else I need to do to fix this?

Comment: @goldylocks From what you said, I thought you put in the input and output file names as they were prompted.  Then you put in the key.  What did you put in for key?  If the integer you put in for key is too large, it could be your problem.

Comment: I typed in key1.txt for the key prompt.

Comment: @goldylocks Oh sorry.  I thought that was your input for the input file name.  In your code, your key variable is an integer and you're trying to input key1.txt, which doesn't make much sense.  Change the key variable to string?

Comment: I really don't know how to pass strings in functions.  How do I take in a string?

Comment: It looks like there's some sort of disconnect.  You're trying to set the integer variable key to key1.txt (based on the input you gave me).  In your encrypt and decrypt functions, you use they integer variable key properly as an integer.  I'm not sure which one is right.  As for passing strings into functions, you passed your input and output C strings into the other functions and you would do the same if you wanted to change key to a string.

Comment: I changed key to a char and that helps but I still get stuck in a loop when I enter either 1 or 2.  I'm not sure how to get it to continue through the encryption or decryption functions.

Comment: You're inputting a file name for key.  You have to read the string from the file to get the actual key because right now you're just using the file name as the key.  There may be other problems with the encrypt and decrypt problems... Still looking

Comment: I think my problem is in the while loop for readText.  I need a way to make the loop walk through the file.  I think I somehow set it up so that buf is equal to reader so it is always true so it is stuck on an infinite loop.

Comment: Edited my post.  Let me know if it helps and if you have more questions.